# Shrink Android make Crash

Tags: android, android-studio, exception, classcastexception

I have upgraded Android Studio.

So, After upgrading it to newest version, I have updated my app with:
    `"shrinkResources true"`, `"minifyEnabled true"`

Unfortunately, am getting crash on some devices, without shrink everything works perfect.

Below is the Log for Crash:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: 

  at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done (AsyncTask.java:354)
  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion (FutureTask.java:383)
  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException (FutureTask.java:252)
  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run (FutureTask.java:271)
  at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run (AsyncTask.java:245)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
  at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:764)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: 
  at android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl.getInt (SharedPreferencesImpl.java:302)
  at com.testApp.preference.WallpaperPreference.getLWPDay (WallpaperPreference.java:66)
  at com.testApp.managerLWP.GetLWP.downloadHouseAds (GetLWP.java:64)
  at com.testApp.managerLWP.GetLWP.doInBackground (GetLWP.java:40)
  at com.testApp.managerLWP.GetLWP.doInBackground (GetLWP.java:22)
  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call (AsyncTask.java:333)
  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run (FutureTask.java:266)
```

Below is the class named `WallpaperPreference` where crash occured.

```
public class WallpaperPreference {
private Context context;
private SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;

public WallpaperPreference(Context context) {
    this.context = context;

    sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
}

public void setLWPDay(int value) {
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putInt(Base.LWP_JSON_DAY, value);
    editor.apply();
}

public int getLWPDay() {
    return sharedPreferences.getInt(Base.LWP_JSON_DAY, 0);
}
```

}

I used:

```
compileSdkVersion 29
buildToolsVersion '29.0.3'
```

What might be the Solution? Thanks.

Comment: Have you set the proguard rules for [shrinking](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code) your app. If not, that's your starting point for this issue. Check if [this article](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/practical-proguard-rules-examples-5640a3907dc9) on medium is of any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. add "debuggable true" in release mode

or

2. change proguard-android-optimize proguard to "proguard-android"

Its works for me